# Chrome Extension query Salesforce

Tags: google-chrome-extension, salesforce

I'm start to create a Chrome Extension for query some object in Salesforce.
There is some way to do this?

1. Open and login into org Salesforce from browser
2. From Chrome Extension get Bearer Token for run a query

I try from get all cookie but still i haven't find any solution..

Thanks for any ideas